# My program has no syntax error but I can't get the final avg # right

Tags: java

My program has no syntax error, I can input all the value, but I just can't get the final average number right. Can anyone help me find out the problem?
The following is what I input:

1. How many employees do you have? 4
2. How many days was Employee #1 absent? 4
3. How many days was Employee #2 absent? 2
4. How many days was Employee #3 absent? 1
5. How many days was Employee #4 absent? 3

Final answer should be:  **2.5**

This is the code I use:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Number {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numEmployee = Number.workers();
        int absentSum = Number.totaldays(numEmployee);
        double averageAbsent = Number.average(numEmployee, absentSum);
    }

    public static int workers() {
        int number = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (number > 0 || number < 0 || number == 0) {
            System.out.println("How many employees do you have?");
            number = input.nextInt();
            if (number >= 0) {
                return number;
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("You can not enter a negative               number."
                                + " Please enter another number.");
            }
        }
        return number;
    }

    public static int totaldays(int numEmployee) {
        int absentDays = 0;
        int absentSum = 0;

        for (int employName = 1; employName <= numEmployee; employName++) {
            System.out.println("How many days was Employee #" + employName
                    + " absent?");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            absentDays = input.nextInt();
            while (absentDays < 0) {
                System.out.println("You can not enter a negative number."
                        + " Please enter another number.");
                System.out.println("How many days was Employee #" + employName
                        + " absent?");
                absentDays = input.nextInt();
            }
            absentSum += absentDays;
        }

        return absentSum;
    }

    public static double average(int numEmployee, int absentSum) {
        double averageAbsent = (double) absentSum / (double) numEmployee;
        System.out.println("Your employees averaged " + averageAbsent
                + " days absent.");
        return averageAbsent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatting to code might make it easier for everyone (including you!) to read this code more easily.

Comment: You can just use a debugger, can you? :)

Answer (score 1):

Move `absentSum += absentDays;` into the loop body in `totaldays`. If you restrict the visibility of `absentSum` then the compiler will tell you that you are accessing it out of scope. Something like

```
public static int totaldays(int numEmployee) {
    int absentSum = 0;

    for (int employName = 1; employName <= numEmployee; employName++) {
        System.out.println("How many days was Employee #" + employName
                + " absent?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int absentDays = input.nextInt();
        while (absentDays < 0) {
            System.out.println("You can not enter a negative number."
                    + " Please enter another number.");
            System.out.println("How many days was Employee #" + employName
                    + " absent?");
            absentDays = input.nextInt();
        }
        absentSum += absentDays;
    }
    // absentSum += absentDays;
    return absentSum;
}
```

With the above output (and your provided input) I get (the requested)

```
2.5
```